# Foundry is showing some remappings I'm not aware of source

Tags: solidity

I have a file called `remappings.txt` containing only:

```
@openzeppelin/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/
```

However, when I prompt `forge remappings` it returns:

```bash
@openzeppelin/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/
ds-test/=lib/forge-std/lib/ds-test/src/
erc4626-tests/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/lib/erc4626-tests/
forge-std/=lib/forge-std/src/
openzeppelin-contracts/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/
openzeppelin/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/
```

My `foundry.toml` does not contain any remappings.

I did not create the other remappings, which means they were automatically created, somehow.
As they are wrong I'd like to remove but I can't locate any remappings file or toml containing it.

I couldn't find any instructions to do so.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

I tried removing it from foundry.toml, cleaning the solidty extesion setting.json and keeping it only at the remappings.txt.

Was expecting to prompt `forge remappings` and see only the content of remappings.txt